# Как правильно составить битовую маску для числа

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер, логика

Подскажите простым человеческим языком - как правильно составлять и использовать битовые маски? Желательно с примерами на Си.

Например, у меня есть int в 6 знаков (если рассматривать десятичное представление), скажем 112 300. Мне необходимо выделить старшие разряды числа (сто десять тысяч) или наоборот (две тысячи триста).

Есть понимание того, что побитовая операция 'И' железно даёт '1' при совпадении битов, но нет понимания (или запутался) того, как правильно оформить маску и выполнить сдвиг для выделения.

Дай Вам Бог терпения, спасибо!

Comment: Битовые маски выделяют *двоичные* разряды числа. Они неприменимы впрямую для выделения *десятичных* разрядов. Разумеется, в конечном итоге через битовые операции можно релизовать что угодно. Однако естественного решения через битовые маски ваша задача-пример не имеет.

Answer (score 8):

Битовые операции предназначены для работы с битами. Нет соответствия между десятичными цифрами и битовой маской. Есть соответствие между шестнадцатеричными цифрами и битовой маской.

Вам надо просто делить число на степень 10 или брать остаток от деления на степень 10, чтобы получить ту или иную часть числа.

Например, чтобы получить `2300` от числа `112 300` вам надо записать выражение

```
112300 % 10000
```

Что касается операторов сдвига >> и <<, то они, фактически, соответственно либо делят нацело число на 2, либо умножают число на 2.

Например, если у вас имеется число `3`, которое в двоичном виде можно представить как `0011`, то после применения оператора `>>` к этом числу вы получите `0001`, то есть 1. Действительно 3 / 2 равно 1 при целочисленных операндах. Если же вы примените оператор <<, то это соответствует умножению, то есть после сдвига влево вы получите число `0110`, которое соответствует 6.

Что касается битовых масок, то очень легко написать функцию, которая предоставляет маску для выделения некоторого непрерывного участка битов числа.

Например

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

unsigned int get_mask( unsigned int pos, unsigned int n )
{
    return ~( ~0 << n ) << pos;
}   

int main() 
{
    unsigned int x = 0xAB;
    unsigned int mask = get_mask( 0, 4 );

    std::cout << std::hex << ( x & mask ) << std::endl;

    mask = get_mask( 4, 4 );

    std::cout << std::hex << ( x & mask ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

вывод программы на консоль

```
b
a0
```

То есть в первом случае применения маски выделились младшие 4 бита. Другие биты числа обнулились. Во втором случае выделились следующие 4 бита числа, а другие биты обнулились.

Или более выразительная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

unsigned int get_mask( unsigned int pos, unsigned int n )
{
    return ~( ~0 << n ) << pos;
}   

int main() 
{
    unsigned int x = 0x12345678;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 2 * sizeof( unsigned int ); i++ )
    {
        unsigned int mask = get_mask( 4 * i, 4 );

        std::cout << std::hex << ( x & mask ) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
8
70
600
5000
40000
300000
2000000
10000000
```

Answer (score 4):

Битовые маски к вашей задаче никакого отношения не имеют.

> у меня есть int в 6 знаков

"int в 6 знаков" не бывает. Бывает `int` размером в `N` битов, где `N` зависит от конкретного железа. "Сколько-то знаков" бывает в строковом представлении числа в определённой системе счисления.

И если речь идёт о десятичной системе, то

> Мне необходимо выделить старшие разряды числа (сто десять тысяч)

```
112300 / 10**4
```

> или наоборот (две тысячи триста).

```
112300 % 10**4
```

В общем случае когда речь о позиционной системе счисления, то делить или брать остаток надо от выражения `основание_СС в степени "позиция нужного разряда"`.

Comment: В вопросах по си не стоит использовать `^` как возведение в степень.

Comment: @Qwertiy, OK :)